# smarty assign to array

Tags: php, smarty

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT blog_title,body FROM blog WHERE post_id='$id' LIMIT 1") or die (mysql_error());

while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
 $tasks[] = $line;
 $group = $tasks['blog_title'];
 $smarty->assign('view', $tasks);
 $smarty->assign('group', $group);
//here the error.i want to assign blog_title to title
 $smarty->assign('title', "Blog - $group");
```

newbie,need help.i want to assign blog_title to title
any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `$tasks`. This variable messes your script up due to the `[]` you're using.
`[] =` works just like creating an array using [array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) and applying [array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) to it.

Here's what you want to achieve:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT blog_title,body FROM blog WHERE post_id='$id' LIMIT 1") or die (mysql_error());

while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $group = $line['blog_title'];
  $smarty->assign('view', $line);
  $smarty->assign('group', $group);
  $smarty->assign('title', "Blog - $group");
}
```

By the way: in the first line (`$result =...` ), ensure that `$id` is properly escaped (see [mysql_real_escape](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)).

Answer (score 0):

You create a 2 dimensional array that's not supposed to be there. Tasks looks like this now:

```
<?php
tasks = array(
      0 => array(
        'blog_title' => 'something'
        'body' => 'something else'
      )
    )
?>
```

So you do $group = $tasks['blog_title'] it does nothing because $tasks only has a key 0, not 'blog_title'.
$group[0]['blog_title'] would work but just remove the tasks assignment altogether.